# How do I convert a javascript object array to a string array of the object attribute I want?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing properties of an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281824/accessing-properties-of-an-array-of-objects)

Given:

```
[{
    'id':1,
    'name':'john'
},{
    'id':2,
    'name':'jane'
}........,{
    'id':2000,
    'name':'zack'
}]
```

What's the best way to get:

```
['john', 'jane', ...... 'zack']
```

Must I loop through and push `item.name` to another array, or is there a simple function to do it?

Comment: Are you sure you need to convert it to an array like that? Oftentimes, doing a conversion like this is an indication that you may be going about your underlying problem the wrong way. It might be useful to take a step back and make sure that's not the case here.

Comment: @shauna my problem is this. im using bootstrap's typeahead it only access the second format: which is a array of string. my ajax calls will return the first format cuz i need the ID. i can of cuz go and extend boostrap's typeahead but rather do this: send the 2nd format to bootstrap. just keep the first format around and when user selects a choice check this first object and use the id as needed.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

If your array of objects is `items`, you can do:

```js
var items = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'john'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'jane'
}, {
  id: 2000,
  name: 'zack'
}];

var names = items.map(function(item) {
  return item['name'];
});

console.log(names);
console.log(items);
```

Documentation: **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

Comment: @bru.scopelliti `map()` is native JavaScript and not just jQuery.

Comment: @bru.scopelliti - my answer has nothing to do with jQuery..

Comment: that's not jQuery. That's just modern javascript. Cool, huh?

Comment: @bru.scopelliti: I don't see any jQuery there.

Comment: since we are using `map` make use of arrow function and we need only single line solution

Comment: You can use more modern syntax like this: names = items.map((item) => item.name);

Comment: names = items.map(item => item.name);

Answer (score 12):

Use the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function native on JavaScript arrays:

```
var yourArray = [ {
    'id':1,
    'name':'john'
},{
    'id':2,
    'name':'jane'
}........,{
    'id':2000,
    'name':'zack'
}];

var newArray = yourArray.map( function( el ){ 
                                return el.name; 
                               });
```

Comment: How can we map JSON structure like this ? `var yourArray = [ 
            {
            "options": [
                {
                    'id':2,
                    'name':'Javascript'
                },{
                    'id':2000,
                    'name':'Ruby'
                }    
            ]
            }];`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this to only monitor own properties of the object:

```
var arr = [];

for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        arr.push(p[key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function createStringArray(arr, prop) {
   var result = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
      result.push(arr[i][prop]);
   }
   return result;
}
```

Just pass the array of objects and the property you need.
The script above will work even in old EcmaScript implementations.