# Get object of object in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I have an array of

```
[{
    "39195": {
        "name": "Introduction",
        "lessons": [{
            "name": "A",
            "duration": "(05:30)",
            "movieName": "Why+Learn+ActionScript%3F"
        }, {
            "name": "About the Included Sample Scripts",
            "duration": "(03:49)"
        }, ]
    },
    "39196": {
        "name": "Introduction2",
        "lessons": [{
            "name": "B",
            "duration": "(05:30)",
            "movieName": "Why+Learn+ActionScript%3F"
        }, {
            "name": "About the Included Sample Scripts",
            "duration": "(03:49)"
        }, ]
    },
    "39197": {
        "name": "Introduction3",
        "lessons": [{
            "name": "C",
            "duration": "(05:30)",
            "movieName": "Why+Learn+ActionScript%3F"
        }, {
            "name": "About the Included Sample Scripts",
            "duration": "(03:49)"
        }, ]
    }
}]
```

How can i get array of values of `[Introduction,Introduction2,Introduction3]`

Comment: are you sure this is valid ?

Comment: Would love to see what you've tried.

Comment: what i mean is the sample above. is it valid?

Comment: @guradio, no it isn't a few commas extra/missing in some places.Just ran it through JSONLINT.

Comment: Yes, this is the response i got from the above api

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973158/how-do-i-convert-a-javascript-object-array-to-a-string-array-of-the-object-attri) SO question. I think it's same requirement.

Comment: So you require the "name" of this json object in array? is the data type known? I mean you know it's the "name" attribute you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** and **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

```js
var arr = [{
  "39195": {
    "name": "Introduction",
    "lessons": [{
      "name": "A",
      "duration": "(05:30)",
      "movieName": "Why+Learn+ActionScript%3F"
    }, {
      "name": "About the Included Sample Scripts",
      "duration": "(03:49)"
    }]
  },
  "39196": {
    "name": "Introduction2",
    "lessons": [{
      "name": "B",
      "duration": "(05:30)",
      "movieName": "Why+Learn+ActionScript%3F"
    }, {
      "name": "About the Included Sample Scripts",
      "duration": "(03:49)"
    }]
  },
  "39197": {
    "name": "Introduction3",
    "lessons": [{
      "name": "C",
      "duration": "(05:30)",
      "movieName": "Why+Learn+ActionScript%3F"
    }, {
      "name": "About the Included Sample Scripts",
      "duration": "(03:49)"
    }]
  }
}];

var res = Object.keys(arr[0]) // get get object keys for iteration
  .map(function(v) { // iterate over the array and retrieve needed property
    return arr[0][v].name // get name property from inner object
  });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick. Set a = to json data

```
var names = [];
for (var key in a[0]) {
  if (a[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert("prop: " + key + " value: " + a[0][key]['name']);
    names.push(a[0][key]['name']);
  }
}
```

If it really is an array then you could add another loop to loop over the array.