# JavaScript React! how to convert array to an array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
const myArray =  ['position zero', 'position one', 'position three', 'position four'];
```

// i neeed to convert it to

```
const objectArray = [
    {
        position: 'position zero'
    },
    {
        position: 'position one'
    },
    {
        position: 'position three'
    },
    {
        position: 'position four'
    },
];
```

// must the same key which i will be refer to all

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Comment: This is the reverse question but you can refer it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973158/how-do-i-convert-a-javascript-object-array-to-a-string-array-of-the-object-attri

Answer (score 3):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over your current array and return the object from map function

```js
const myArray =  ['position zero', 'position one', 'position three', 'position four'];

const res = myArray.map(data => {
    return {position: data}
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Consider marking  the answer as accepted, if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map` with `Shorthand property names`.

```js
const myArray =  ['position zero', 'position one', 'position three', 'position four'],
      result = myArray.map(position => ({position}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` here:

```
const result = myArray.map(s => ({position: s}));
```

**Demo:**

```js
const myArray =  ['position zero', 'position one', 'position three', 'position four'];

const result = myArray.map(s => ({position: s}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

User `array.map` with ES6's `shorthand object litteral`:

```js
const myArray =  ['position zero', 'position one', 'position three', 'position four'];

const res = myArray.map(position => ({position}));
console.log(res);
```