# How to construct a new array with values of existing objects array in react javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

let's say I have an array:

```
arr = [
    {id: 1 , content: 'content string 1' , ... }
    {id: 2 , content: 'content string 2' , ... }
    {id: 3 , content: 'content string 3' , ... }
    {id: 4 , content: 'content string 4' , ... }
    {id: 5 , content: 'content string 5' , ... }
]
```

I want to get content string from this array and put this into a new array
Like:

```
newArray = ['content string 1', 'content string 2', 'content string 3', 'content string 4', 'content string 5' ]
```

I've seen many articles on web for the methods to copy values from objects into new array, but not seems to be working.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13973194/14021955

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const arr = [
    {id: 1 , content: 'content string 1'  },
    {id: 2 , content: 'content string 2'  },
    {id: 3 , content: 'content string 3'  },
    {id: 4 , content: 'content string 4'  },
    {id: 5 , content: 'content string 5'  }
]

const newArr = arr.map((item) => item.content)

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: This is an **often-repeated** duplicate question. Please don't post answers to obvious duplicates.

Comment: Please vote to close duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
const newArray = arr.map(element => element.content);
```

Comment: This is an **often-repeated** duplicate question. Please don't post answers to obvious duplicates. Also, code-only answers aren't useful answers. It's important to explain what you did.